# MS SQL Server: Change time of a smalldatetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a `SMALLDATETIME` column and several records with wrong time. e.g.:

`2018-07-17 11:06:00`

the correct time is `00:00:00`, so, for all those entries, I want to change the time to that value (`2018-07-17 00:00:00`).

In the table the greatest part of records have the correct time.

What's the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: So, should every value be at midnight (`'00:00:00'`)? Why not, instead, use the `date` datatype then if the time has no baring?

Comment: yes, every value should be at midnight. I cannot change the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @datetime SMALLDATETIME ='2018-07-17 11:06:00'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, @datetime))
```

So something like that :

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET MY_COLUMN = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, MY_COLUMN))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want time you can use `cast( as date)` to drop time component & set it to `00:00:00`

```
update t 
     set dt = cast(dt as date);
```

Comment: I would like to add a select to apply the `SET` only to records with time != midnight